# Minor changes in Help Center pages

Tags: feature-request, help-center

## [/help/dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

---

1. In the fourth paragraph:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

In the last line, "our real time web chat" link should preferably point to https://chat.stackoverflow.com or at least https://chat.stackexchange.com or whatever the respective chat URL is for the site.

---

2. In the last paragraph:

> If your question is about the site itself, please don't ask it here. Visit our meta-discussion site, where you can talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags should be used, suggest a feature, point out a bug, or generally discuss how this site works.

In the second sentence, "our meta-discussion" can be linked to https://meta.stackoverflow.com as similar phrase in other pages has been linked to the site-meta too.

---

*I also looked at the same help page of [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) and it looks like all three **may** be carbon copies- so this question would probably fit better on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) if [all the SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) have the same text in the Help Center.*

---

## [/help/dmca-takedown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dmca-takedown)

---

3. In the last paragraph, it is written like so:

> You can submit the counter-notice to us through our [/contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page by selecting the "I want to send a DMCA Notice or Counterclaim" option.

But when we go to [that page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) the option mentioned is hidden under the "Trust and Safety" category.

So I suggest that just to avoid any potential confusion or just to make things clear the text be changed to something like this (the **bold** part indicates the proposed changes):

> You can submit the counter-notice to us through our [/contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page by selecting the "I want to send a DMCA Notice or Counterclaim" option **present under the "Trust and Safety" category**.

---

## [/help/more-help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/more-help)

---

4. In the first paragraph:

> If you’re looking for more details or context about this community’s policies, our [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) hosts a section of constantly evolving [frequently asked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) that documents everything about the site. (For more information, see this Help Center article: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta))

The "frequently asked questions" link points to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq, which presents the user looking for help with unorganized and random [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions.

I am of the opinion that the link should point to the [FAQ Index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) instead so that the user will be presented with a neater, organized list where they can, well, get help more efficiently.

---

What does the community think about these changes?

---

*p.s. I combined many proposals in one post by deleting a previous separate one and adding its content here as I thought that only 1-2 proposals wouldn't be worthy enough of a whole meta post.*

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong about not having only 1-2 minor proposals for a whole meta post. Although, there would be a problem with what to status-tag the question with if the team agrees with 1 proposal but disagrees with another one

Comment: Last I checked, we don't have access to change any of this - it must be done by staff.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know that, I just thought that it may be a problem for staff :)